# Vimeo Desktop App OAuth

Tags: oauth, vimeo, token

I'm currently having massive trouble with Vimeo's Oauth implementation and my desktop app. My program does the following correctly.

1- Requests a Unauthorized Request Token with my key and secret and returns - a Token and a Token secret.

2- Generates a URL for the user to go to using the token which then shows our application's name and allows the user to Authorize us to use his/her account. It then shows a verifier which the user returns and puts into our app.

The problem is the third step and actually exchanging the tokens for the access tokens. Basically every time we try and get them we get a "Invalid / expired token - The oauth_token passed was either not valid or has expired"

I looked at the documentation and there's supposed to be a callback to a server when deployed like that which gives the user an "authorized token" but as im developing a desktop app we can't do this. So I assume the token retrieved in 1 is valid for this step. (actually it seems it is: http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:22605)

So I'm wondering now am I missing something here on my actual vimeo application account now? is it treating it as a web hosted app with callbacks? all the elements are there for this to work and I've used this same component to create a twitter Oauth login in exactly the same way and it was fine.

Thanks in advance,

Barry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It was a problem on Vimeo's end.